# How do I access an object's properties by name?

Tags: python

```
class a(type):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'aaa'
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        attrs['cool']='cool!!!!'
        new_class = super(a,cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
                #if 'media' not in attrs:
                    #new_class.media ='media'
        return new_class

class b(object):
    __metaclass__=a
    def __str__(self):
        return 'bbb'

print b
print b()['cool']#how can i print 'cool!!!!'
```

Comment: Just in case people don't read past the title, you should try to make it reflect the rest of your question.

Comment: Printing Foo or Bar(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar) is cooler!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print b().cool
```

`attrs` in your `__new__` method becomes the object's dictionary. Properties of Python objects are referenced with the `.` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
print "cool!!!"
```

Or did I miss something?

Comment: I got a laugh outta your answer